# Do we get an information about the extrema from the graph?

Tags: calculus, optimization, graphing-functions

We have the function $f(x,y)=x^2y$.

We want to find the extrema under the constraint $3x+2y=9$.

Solving for one variable at the equation of the constraint and getting then a function of one variable we get the following:

$f(x,y)$ has a local maximum at $\left (2, \frac{3}{2}\right )$ and a local minimum at $\left (0, \frac{9}{2}\right )$

When's we draw some contour lines and the constraint can we get also from there an information about the extrema?

The graph for the contour lines $f(x,y)=c$, where $c\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the constraint is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Basically, when our functions and constraints are smooth, a necessary condition for a point $(x_0,y_0)$ to be an extremum over the constraint set $3x+2y=9$ is that the level set of $f(x,y)$ through $(x_0,y_0)$ touches the line $3x+2y=9$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. Equivalently (and which is easier to deal with in practice), the gradient $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ should be orthogonal to the line $3x+2y=9$. The intuition is that if the gradient had a component along the direction of the constraint line, we would be able to make a small move along that component and opposite to it to increase/reduce the function value.

Comment: I added a picture of that graph at my initial post. At $(0,\frac{9}{2})$ the line $3x+2y=9$ doesn't touch the level set of $f(x,y)$, does it?

Comment: The gradient of $f$ is zero at that point - it's a critical point. So the dot product is zero. Formally not orthogonal but the next best thing. ;)